# DynamoDB takes too much time to respond for a single item

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Go REST service which connects to DynamoDB to retrieve some products. The table has around 100.000 products, and I usually retrieve around 20.0000 (which then get filtered down by other processes before actually replying but thats irrelevant to my problem).

The problem I see is my entire request takes around 4 seconds, which is very high for my goals. I started logging each layer in my app until finally reaching the smallest part which is each individual retrieval of an item from the DB.

To my surprise, **each item retrieval takes approximately 3.6 seconds**??!!.

Regardless of the below code, what might be the causes of this? Is something I am missing on the configuration for dynamo?

```
func (db DynamoRepository) FetchProducts(c *gin.Context, pID string) ([]models.Product, error) {
    output := make([]models.Product, 0)
    chProduct := make(chan *models.Product)

    sem := make(chan struct{}, 40000)
    wait := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wait.Add(1)
    go func (wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < len(itemIDs); i++ {
            p := <-chProduct
            if p != nil {
                output = append(output, *p)
            }
        }
        close(chProduct)
    }(&wait)
    for index := range itemIDs {
        sem <- struct{}{}
        go func(ix int, s chan struct{}, ch chan *models.Product) {
            defer func() {
               <- s
            }()
            infoSlice := strings.Split(itemIDs[ix], "_")
            if len(infoSlice) != 2 {
                ch <- nil
                return
            }
            key := map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                "PK": {
                    N: aws.String(pID),
                },
                "SK": {
                    S: aws.String("product"),
                },
            }
            start := time.Now()
            result, err := db.DB.GetByKey(c, db.Config.AWS.Table, key)
            fmt.Printf("Item %s took %d\n", productID, time.Since(start).Milliseconds())
            if err != nil {
                ch <- nil
                return
            }
            if result.Item == nil {
                ch <- nil
                return
            }
            var product models.Product
            err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &product)
            if err != nil {
                ch <- nil
                return
            }
            ch <- &product
        }(index, sem, chProduct)
    }
    wait.Wait()

    if len(output) == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }
    return output, nil
}
```

The implementation of GetByKey:

```
func (provider *DynamoDBProvider) GetByKey(ctx context.Context, tableName string, key map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue) (*dynamodb.GetItemOutput, error) {
    input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
        Key:       key,
    }

    result, err := provider.client.GetItem(input)

    return result, err
}
```

Comment: When using other clients to connect to your DynamoDB instance, how big of a difference there is in the time? It may be a network latency issue.  Also, BatchGetItem allows you to get up to 100 objects at a time, it's gonna be way faster than getting them individually.

Comment: Hi Mikael, Ill eventually change the implementation to BatchGetItem, but still this issue will slow down the process too much.

Comment: Regarding other clients, other Go projects are using the same SDK and it works fine for them

Comment: Is your capacity on-demand or provisioned?

Comment: What is your background throughput? If you are going from 0 reads to 20,000, DynamoDB is unlikely to be able to scale throughput instantly. Does your response time decrease if you repeat the test (i.e. you warm the database up)?

Comment: hi. yes. it decreases, but never below 1.5~ seconds which is an inmense amount of time. im not very sure if its on demand or provisioned

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing, and it greatly improved the latency. I followed this guide to create a custom HTTP client :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/custom-http.html

The latency went from almost 4 seconds to 500ms~. Why? I have no idea but it worked.

Comment: Would it be possible to include your custom HTTP client code? I'm running into a similar issue